# Which languages have a primitive operation for swapping variables?

Tags: variables, programming-languages, language-features

In most languages, if you want to swap two variables, it's something like:

```
var c = b
b = a
a = c
```

Yes, you can do fancy hacks with XOR if you like but it's generally 3 lines of code for a single operation. Are there any languages that have swapping variables as a primitive in the language?

Comment: Just to be clear, even if it's primitive to the language, it's still potentially translated to 3 distinct operations in machine code, unless your machine code supports pure swapping (on x86, you can use the XCHG operator, but that implies you also want to synchronize access to the memory, which may actually make it slower). So in other words, how many lines of code something is in your language of choice really has little bearing on what actually happens in compiled/jitted code and as such may have very little effect on actual code perf.

Comment: The XOR trick is not a fancy hack, it's an abomination. If you're running in a system that can't spare a tiny bit of extra storage for a temporary, the extra CPU load of boolean operations over a simple transfer sequence will also probably bring you down. Sometimes, you should just optimise for readability :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua, Python, Ruby and more support this notation:

```
a, b = b, a
```

And javascript sure needs no temporary variable either ;)

```
a = -(b = (a += b) - b) + a;
```

For more examples on how to swap variables (in 86 languages), see: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Generic_swap

Answer (score 4):

In most dynamic languages you can do something like this to swap:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Now a have the value of b, and b has the value of a. I am not sure if this is what you meant or not.